# Calculate value in Columne based on two other columns Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the mean value for the two classes Physics and Math and include it in a seperate Column Mean. Furthermore I am just trying to calculate the mean for classes wher both need a grade. This is working to make a filter. The only think which is not working is to calculate the Mean value. For the missing ones it works but somehow it sets the ones where I have a value to zero which is weird. The data looks like the following:

```
Date        School  Math    Physics Mean    Flag
01.01.2020  ABC     3       4               1
01.03.2020  ABC     2       3               1
01.05.2020  ABC     2       1       1.5     2
01.07.2020  ABC     2       1               1
01.08.2020  ABC     2       1       1.5     2
01.04.2020  ABC     2                       3
01.06.2020  ABC             1               3
```

My code looks as the following:

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'School_grades.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(path)
df_copy = df.copy(deep=True)

df_copy['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_copy.Date)

df_copy = df_copy[(df_copy["Flag"] != 3)]

df_copy['Mean'] = ((df_copy['Math'] + df_copy['Physics'])/2).where(df_copy['Flag'] == 1)

print(df_copy)
```

My code provides the following where the columns where I had already Means included to NaN:

```
       Date     School  Math  Physics  Mean  Flag
0 2020-01-01    ABC     3.0   4.0      3.5     1
1 2020-01-03    ABC     2.0   3.0      2.5     1
2 2020-01-05    ABC     2.0   1.0      NaN     2
3 2020-01-07    ABC     2.0   1.0      1.5     1
4 2020-01-08    ABC     2.0   1.0      NaN     2
```

But would rather expect something like this:

```
       Date     School  Math  Physics  Mean  Flag
0 2020-01-01    ABC     3.0   4.0      3.5     1
1 2020-01-03    ABC     2.0   3.0      2.5     1
2 2020-01-05    ABC     2.0   1.0      1.5     2
3 2020-01-07    ABC     2.0   1.0      1.5     1
4 2020-01-08    ABC     2.0   1.0      1.5     2
```

Comment: Probably something to do with `.where(df_copy['Flag'] == 1)` as the `NaN` items have `2` in the `Flag` column.

Comment: @Ouroborus, thanks for the reply. I only need to calculate the Mean where the mean is missing. Flag 1 shows that mean is missing. So how can I only calculate where Flag == 1 where it is 2 the mean value exisits so no need to recalculate. Is it a little bit clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .where() method has no "else" statement but return a series for each row of the dataframe. This means it only return values where your where statement is True and missing values where it is False, essentially throwing your previous results away.
There are multiple way to solve this. One is the following using numpy library.

np.where() essentially has a series with True/False values. Where True use the next provided series, where false use the last provided series. Here we insert the previous mean values.

```
import numpy as np
df_copy['Mean'] = np.where(df_copy['Flag'] == 1, ((df_copy['Math'] + df_copy['Physics'])/2), df_copy['Mean'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I gorgot that numpy has something similar :).

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add the `other` parameter in [`pandas.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where)

```
>> df_copy['Mean'] = ((df_copy['Math'] + df_copy['Physics'])/2).where(df_copy['Flag'] == 1,df_copy['Mean'])
>> print(df_copy)

  Date        School  Math  Physics  Mean  Flag
0  01.01.2020    ABC   3.0      4.0   3.5     1
1  01.03.2020    ABC   2.0      3.0   2.5     1
2  01.05.2020    ABC   2.0      1.0   1.5     2
3  01.07.2020    ABC   2.0      1.0   1.5     1
4  01.08.2020    ABC   2.0      1.0   1.5     2
5  01.04.2020    ABC   2.0      NaN   NaN     3
6  01.06.2020    ABC   NaN      1.0   NaN     3
```

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) to calculate the average

```
df_copy['Mean'] = df_copy[['Math','Physics']].mean(axis=1).where(df_copy.Flag == 1,df_copy['Mean'])
```

You can also use the [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
df_copy['Mean'] = np.where(df_copy.Flag == 1,df_copy[['Math','Physics']].mean(axis=1),df_copy['Mean'])
```